# JavaScript Random Number Function Script Build

Tags: javascript, random

I am new to JS, and I am looking for a line by line walk through for an example I am working in
my JS textbook. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<script>
      var total = 0;
      for (i=1; i<=5000; i++) {
        var num = Math.random();
        total += num;
        if (i % 1000 == 0) {
           document.write("Generated " + i + " numbers...<br>");
         }
      }
      var average = total / 5000;
      average = Math.round(average * 1000) / 1000;
      document.write("<h2>Average of 5000 numbers is: " +
                     average + "</h2>");
    </script>
```

Comment: I am especially having a hard time understanding the "if (i % 1000...)" and everything after "var average"

Comment: Have a look into the modulo operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Math#Arithmetic_operators

Comment: @Dominik yes, just having a hard time grasping the concept...

Comment: add a console.log after each line and see how the values of the variables change. Read the documentation for each operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you initialize a variable `total=0`.
Then, counting from 1 to 5000, at each iteration you create a new random float between 0 and 1 and store it in `num`. You add this to `total`.

Now the line you are confused about. It is essentially a simple progress bar kind of thing. After every 1000 iterations of the loop, it prints how many iterations has happened to the document (screen). The `if(i%1000 == 0)` block runs 5 times throughout this code, at i = 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000.

Once the loop is completed, we compute the average number generated. I'm sure you know that average = sum/count. In this case sum is stored in `total` and count is the number of loop iterations, which is 5000, so you have `average = total/5000`.

Now remember that `average` is a float between 0 and 1, because you have taken the average of 5000 floats between 0 and 1 (basic math). You multiply this number by 1000, round it to its nearest integer and then divide by 1000 again. The purpose of this is unclear (should be mentioned with the code, but my guess is that it cuts the float to atmost 3 decimal places.

Lastly, you print the average to the document.

An example output would look like:

```
Generated 1000 numbers...
Generated 2000 numbers...
Generated 3000 numbers...
Generated 4000 numbers...
Generated 5000 numbers...
Average of 5000 numbers is 0.5
```

Comment: great answer, although I do have a question. "Now the line you are confused about. It is essentially a simple progress bar kind of thing. After every 1000 iterations of the loop, it prints how many iterations has happened to the document (screen). The if(i%1000 == 0) block runs 5 times throughout this code, at i = 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000."   what is the value of i during the check? How I am perceiving it is @ i = 1000 you have a remainder of 0 which gives you the first value of i = 1000. @ i = 2000 you get a remainder of 0 which gives you the i=2000 so on and so forth... is that correct?

Comment: " In this case sum is stored in total".. can you please give me an example of a total value so I can work through an example numerically?

Comment: Yup, your understanding of the remainder idea is correct. Because of how math works, at the end of the loop, `total` will always be around 2500, maybe a little lower like 2498.342 or higher like 2504.232, but always around that range.